# Android doesn't grab new json file

Tags: android, json, file, download

I am developing an app that grabs a new json file every time is starts. But I've found that even though I delete the file and download the new one, the phone somehow still ends up with the old file.

Delete code:

```
if (test.exists()) {
            test.delete();
            Log.i(TAG, "Deleting File");
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "File does not exist");
}
```

Download Code:

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(path));
    request.setTitle("stations.json");
    request.setDescription("File is being downloaded.....");
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE);
    request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(getApplicationContext(), null, "stations.json");
    request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false);


    manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    jsonRef = manager.enqueue(request);
```

I've deleted the file myself from the storage. It still grabs the old file. I've checked in a browser if the server version is updated. It was. I'm at a loss as to what may be happening. If the Stack community has any suggestions, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much!

Comment: Is it possible that it's being cached? Can you try appending the url with `?v=" + Math.random()`?

Comment: Did you delete the file manually and after downloading the old file showed up ?

Comment: Yes, that's what happened. @MCZ

Comment: @DaveChen How does that work? If I add that to the end of the url, won't it mess it up?

Comment: No it won't. It's just a random get variable. Try it. "stations.json?v=" + Math.random()

Comment: your problem is not about saving new file is all about downloading it. need more code to find the problem

Comment: That seemed to fix the problem. Thanks so much! @DaveChen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that my phone was somehow caching the file. It would see that I was downloading the same file and would instead just give it to me. By giving it a new url, it tricked the app into thinking it was a new file.

In the end, what worked was to add:

```
?v=" + Math.random()
```

to the end of the file.

For Example:

```
String path = example.com/stations.json?v=" + Math.random();
```

Then download with:

```
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(path));
```